# EF Core did join on his own?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I've just witnessed something weird

Let's consider this example

```
publi class Order
{
    (...)
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    (...)
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

context
.Orders
.Include(x => x.Owner)
.Where(x => x.Owner.Id = 123)
.Where(x => x.Status.Name == "asdf")
.ToList();
```

I was shocked when this code worked properly - it found only those orders with `status name`==`asdf` for Owner with an `Id`=`123` (`he had orders of other type also`) and I even found that Status is being inner joined

but why? there's no Include

Is it possible or I'll have to try to find bug somewhere else?

Comment: It because up until you do `ToList()` you are still building a query (`IQueryable`) and while querying you can access those records. EFCore is smart enough to see you are referring to those fields in your query and when evaluating the query, will join for you. If you put the `where`'s after the `ToList()` it will crash on the `.Where(x => x.Status.Name == "asdf")` line

Comment: That's just how EF (Core) works. `Include` is all about *loading* related data, not *filtering*.

Comment: @KirkLarkin holy, so I do not have to use ``Include`` to be able to filter data?

Comment: Indeed. If you're not accessing `Owner` data in your example after the call to `ToList()`, you don't need the `Include` for that either. Give it a try.

Comment: Be aware that unused includes are a pathway to exceptions - as per [this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14671) from the EF Core GitHub.

Comment: @JamieTaylor Apparently I'll have to deal with a lot of exceptions after upgrading to newest EF Core ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Include` is an instruction to [eager-load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) related data in the same LINQ statement. It's not a "declaration" of navigation properties you're going to use later for filtering or selecting. I often see this confusion. Let's summarize it:

### Include is not necessary for

- Filtering data

  ```
  context.Orders
         .Where(x => x.Owner.Id = 123)
         .Where(x => x.Status.Name == "In progress")
  ```

  ...generates SQL with two `JOIN`s and returns filtered `Orders`, no `Owner` or `Status` included.

  ```
  context.Orders
         .Include(o => o.Owner)
         .Where(x => x.Owner.Id = 123)
         .Where(x => x.Status.Name == "In progress")
  ```

  ...returns filtered `Orders` with only `Owner` included.
- Selecting data

  ```
  context.Orders
         .Select(x => new
         { 
             x.Number,
             Owner = x.Owner.Name, 
             Status = x.Status.Name
         }
  ```

  ...again generates SQL with two joins and returns anonymous type objects, no `Owner`, no `Status`.

  ```
  context.Orders
         .Include(o => o.Owner)
         .Select(x => new
         { 
             x.Number,
             Owner = x.Owner.Name, 
             Status = x.Status.Name
         }
  ```

  ...returns exactly the same data because the `Include` is [ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes). If there's nothing in the end result that can contain the `Include`d data the `Include` will be ignored.

Note that `Include` does have effect in a query like

```
context.Orders
       .Include(o => o.Owner)
       .Select(x => new
       { 
           Order = x,
           Owner = x.Owner.Name, 
           Status = x.Status.Name
       }
```

Even though an anonymous type is returned, the `Order` in it is the container of `Owner` and `Owner` is included. This was different in EF 6 (and I guess still in EF 6.3 on .NET Core 3.0), there the latter `Include` was also ignored.